# Xamarin Forms Set specific value in CollectionView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created a CollectionView with as content a List with Images. The myImage class looks like this:

```
public class myImage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ImageSource imageSource { get; set; }
}
```

Now in the CollectionView I also have a picker with a List with Sizes. That class looks like this:

```
public class Format
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Size{ get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

What I want is that when the myImage.Type has a specific value, for example "type1", that the only option in the picker will be the Size where `Format.Type="type1"`. For the rest, the whole List can be displayed in the picker except for the Format where `Format.Type = "type1"`.

So I want a CollectionView with Images, next to the image there is a picker. If the myImage.Type="type1" the picker will be filled with Formats where Type="type1". The rest of the image gets the Formats where Format.Type="Normal".

Here is my xaml:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid HeightRequest="100" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ff:CachedImage  Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding imageSource}" />

        <Picker Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="3" Title="Formaat" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:VM_FotoLijst}}, Path=formaatList}"
                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Size}" PropertyChanged="FormaatPicker_PropertyChanged"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. So you want to change the data shown in the picker depending on whether Type has a certain value or not.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use two different item templates based on the value of your type. In each of those templates you can point your picker's itemsource to an individual source.

A custom [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector) will allow you to switch the item's DataTemplate based on the item's properties. The following custom DataTemplateSelector code should work for your use case. I also added some XAML outlining how you can define the two data templates you want to switch between. At the very end there is an example of how to set this data template selector on your CollectionView.

**Code**

```
public class ImageTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate NormalTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate SpecialTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        if (item is null) return NormalTemplate;

        if (item is myImage image)
        {
            if (image.Type == "type1")
                return SpecialTemplate;
            else
                return NormalTemplate;
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(ImageTemplateSelector));
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="normalImageTemplate">
        <!--all the image related controls-->
        <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding NormalPickerSource}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="specialImageTemplate">
        <!--all the image related controls-->
        <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding SpecialPickerSource}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:ImageTemplateSelector x:Key="imageTemplateSelector"
        NormalTemplate="{StaticResource normalImageTemplate}"
        SpecialTemplate="{StaticResource specialImageTemplate}" />
</ResourceDictionary>

<CollectionView ItemSource="{Binding YourItems}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource imageTemplateSelector}">
</CollectionView>
```